# Popup still shows when not minimized

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a simple pop up behavior for a custom search control:

The popup behavior works as normal:

Open:

[image]

Closed:

[image]

The pop up opens and closed using a bool `HasText`:

```
                        <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="HasText" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="SearchButtonImage" Value="cancel.png"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsOpen" TargetName="childPop" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="HasText" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="SearchButtonImage" Value="search.png"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsOpen" TargetName="childPop" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
```

However when the application is not minimized the popup appears over other applications:
[image]

When the application is minimized the popup is hidden.

Do I have to add handling that checks if the window is 'Active'? Or any other implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have:

```
<Popup StaysOpen="False" />
```

> When StaysOpen is false, the Popup control intercepts all mouse and
>   keyboard events to determine when one of these events occurs outside
>   the Popup control.